# RDS drive redirection does not work

Tags: windows, azure, cloud, driver, rds

I have a virtual machine on Azure which I connect to through a RDP session. I want to redirect my local C: drive to this VM but, when I connect through RDP I cannot see my local drive. When I try to type \\tsclient it does not work either.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on the issue and what you have attempted to resolve it?

Comment: I have VM on azure. when i connect to this vm through RDS i share my local C: driver. i like to see this drive inside VM. I configure my Remote desktop connection to share drive c: but when i go inside VM i can not see C: drive even i try \\tsclient i get empty folder!!

Comment: `net use H: \\IP\d /persistent:yes` What is the result? Do you check your share permission?

Comment: Grammar/language fixes for clarity (driver vs drive)

Comment: Change slashes for drive name.